# Add single pin to Mapkit with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, mapkit, swiftui

How can I add a simple pin on my map with Xcode 11 GM / SwiftUI.

My code is as follows (here it shows me the map centered with the coordinates) but I want to show there only one pin of other coordinates.

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct ContentView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        MKMapView(frame: .zero)
    }

    func updateUIView(_ view: MKMapView, context: Context) {
        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
            latitude: 34.011_286, longitude: -116.166_868)
        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 2.0, longitudeDelta: 2.0)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: span)
        view.setRegion(region, animated: true)



    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any suggestions, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your code:

```
struct ContentView: UIViewRepresentable {


    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        MKMapView(frame: .zero)
    }

    func updateUIView(_ view: MKMapView, context: Context) {


        // 1 
        view.mapType = MKMapType.standard // (satellite)

        // 2
        let mylocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -6.863190,longitude: -79.818250)

        // 3
        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
            latitude: -6.864138, longitude: -79.819634)
        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.005, longitudeDelta: 0.005)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: span)
        view.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        // 4
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = mylocation

        annotation.title = "My Location"
        annotation.subtitle = "Visit us soon"
        view.addAnnotation(annotation)






    }
}
```

[image: Preview]

Answer (score 0):

Found this post looking for how to add a simple pin/marker to XCode's MapKit and SwiftUI tutorials. Sharing a workable answer for using the new `Map` SwiftUI View rather than the more complex `MKMapView` in OP's question.

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct Marker: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var location: MapMarker
}

struct MapView: View {
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
   
    @State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion()
    @State var markers = [Marker(location: MapMarker(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -25.342863, longitude: 131.036974), tint: .blue))]
    
    var body: some View {
        Map(coordinateRegion: $region, annotationItems: markers) { marker in
            marker.location }
            .onAppear {
                setRegion(coordinate)
            }
    }
    
    private func setRegion(_ coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
         region = MKCoordinateRegion(
             center: coordinate,
             span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.2, longitudeDelta: 0.2)
         )
         markers = [Marker(location: MapMarker(coordinate: coordinate, tint: .blue))]
     }
}

struct MapView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MapView(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -25.342863, longitude: 131.036974))
    }
}
```